# Is it possible to modify a global variable in a nested if statement?

Tags: python-3.7

I'm trying to make a simple text based game thing just for fun/practice since I'm a dumb newbie and in my mind, I could make my code work IF I could just get a global variable to change when I want it to (if the player solves the puzzle correctly, it would change the answers to the questions, and you can continue through the game, if you can even call it a game).

I basically started with just stating computerNumber = computerNumber + 1 in order to change a whole bunch of other variables, then looked at youtube videos and some stack overflow things about variables in functions being able to effect global variables by adding "global" in front of them, so I made a function that looks like this

```
 def function():
     global computerNumber
     computerNumber = computerNumber + 1
     return
function()
```

but it still doesn't seem to reach the global variable, just changing the variable within the if statement. I could have sworn I put the project in here when I initially made this post (it's fairly small), but I'm also new to posting on stack overflow, so I don't know what I'm doing with this either I suppose.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The answer to the question in the title is "yes, it's possible" but that won't help you solve the problem. You have to show your code before we can tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1na61OUws8yVAlzzK40dbnJpXuyKRdW8o/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                                                                         so I'm sharing a link to a google drive file because I don't know how to (or if I even can) add the code to stack overflow. Thank you for welcoming me, and thank you for replying. I have been super busy with life stuff recently, so hopefully, you're still interested in aiding a poor dumb internet lad with this problem.  Let me know if you have any access issues.